# External ThunderBolt 3 SSD drive not recognized on Ubuntu 17.10 running on Macbook Pro A1706

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, thunderbolt

So I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 on an external SSD and had it boot on my MacBook Pro A1706 (late 2016), works like a charm (installed the keyboard/touchbar module).

I have an external ThunderBolt 3 (USB type C) SSD drive. When I connect it, Ubuntu doesn't recognize it. lspci shows Thunderbolt is available. When connecting the drive to MacOS, it works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anything in the logfiles when you plug it in?  Does it work if you plug it in before booting from the other SSD?

Comment: What filesystem is the partition formatted to?

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbolt requires either that you manually authorize your devices. However no utility exists in current distributions for that. You can either try compiling yourself the `tbtadm` utility found here:
https://github.com/intel/thunderbolt-software-user-space

Or go the unsafe way as [described in the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/thunderbolt.html):

*Those users who just want to connect any device without any sort of manual work, can add following line to /etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules:*

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="thunderbolt", ATTR{authorized}=="0", ATTR{authorized}="1"
```

*This will authorize all devices automatically when they appear. However, keep in mind that this bypasses the security levels and makes the system vulnerable to DMA attacks.*