# Do Thunderbolt 3 external SSDs work with Linux?

Tags: linux, ssd, lenovo-laptop, thunderbolt

I'm planning to buy and connect an external SSD to a Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen 5 laptop, using one of the Thunderbolt 3 connectors of the laptop, with a Thunderbolt 3 cable. ([Example](http://www.sonnettech.com/product/fusiontb3pcieflashdrive.html) of such an external SSD.) Does Linux support Thunderbolt 3 storage devices? Which kernel do I need? Which module (driver) do I need?

Please note that I'm not interested in SATA. The example SSD above uses NVMe rather than SATA. (SATA is slower than what high-end SSDs provide over Thunderbolt 3.)

Please note that I'm not interested in the USB protocol (not even USB 3.1, Type C connector, Gen 2). Thunderbolt 3 uses the USB Type C connector, but it supports multiple protocols (e.g. Thunderbolt 3, USB 3.1, DisplayPort, PCI Express). I want to connect the SSD to the laptop using a protocol faster than USB 3.1.

Please note that I'm not interested in replacing the internal SSD in the laptop with a faster one using NVMe. (I've done that already, and I also need an external SSD.)

FYI a similar question for an external Thunderbolt 3 SSD on a MacBook running Linux (without answer): [External ThunderBolt 3 SSD drive not recognized on Ubuntu 17.10 running on Macbook Pro A1706](https://superuser.com/q/1298144/19956)

Comment: I've connected a LaCIe TB drive to a Debian machine. Thunderbolt driver loads, but no device appears...